# Cross account access with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have API gateway deployed in Account A, and want to authenticate/allow other Account B,C,D. In actual use case, I want to authenticate more than 50 AWS account. Scale in and scale out as required.

Tried the below approach, andimplementation is working:

**Resource based policy**:
To  authenticate within various AWS account. But the problem is I have to redeploy my API to reflect the changes.

**Cognito**
It can be use if the users need to sign-up and sign-in
Not suitable in the given scenario, we validating authentication between accounts

**REST API Private**
Again, in the resource policy I have to provide the endpoint details. But the problem is I have to redeploy my API to reflect the changes.

**Lambda authorizer on cross account**
We can deploy authorizer in individual AWS accounts, but authentication should be centralized in source account.

I probably think answer revolves around Lambda authorizer, but not sure how can I go forward from here.

Do we have any approach to authenticate, If you guide me some with documentation I can refer, it will be great help.

Comment: Why is a redeployment a problem? That is one API call that is done in a few milliseconds.

Comment: Hi @luk2302, consider REST API Private approach how can i manage resource policy definition, add and remove multiple vpc endpoint... 

"Condition": {
                "StringEquals": [
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-05983252a951bb", and so on..

                [
            }